# Does Minimum damage and Maximum damage tooltip make sense?

Tags: diablo-iii

> Minimum damage and Maximum damage values will now display separately in an item's tooltip (i.e. "+2-4 Damage" will now display as "+2 Minimum Damage” and “+2 Maximum Damage")

Isn't that counter-intuitive?

I simply don't get how this is meant to be logical and make sense.
Every time I look at it, i think to myself, "Add the two to get the actual maximum".

Have I misunderstood this calculation entirely? Or do you all agree that the tooltip is confusing?

Maybe someone can post calculations that explain why this way makes more sense.

**EDIT**

I still need a conclusive answer (or confirmation) to the below:

An item with `10 - 12 damage` gets a modifier of `+2 min / +2 max` (or `+2-4` as per the pre 1.0.3 tooltip).

Does this item scale to `12 - 14 damage` ?

If the same item gets  `+3 min / +3 max` (in this case, old tooltip listed `+3-6`?), does it scale to 13 - 16 or 13 - 15 ?

How does one explain what the old tooltip did? i.e. what does the `6` mean in `+3-6` as per above?

Comment: To use your example, an item with `10-12` that gets a `+2/+2` modifier would increase to `12-15`. If it received a bonus of `+3/+3`, it would increase to `13-17`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If an items does `10 - 15` base-damage and you put in a gem that adds `+2 min / +2 max` the new damage range is `12 - 17 damage`.

Before the patch, the calculation was exactly the same, but `+2-4 damage` is much more confusing (in my opinion). The new wording just clarifies what *really* happens.

**EDIT:**
Explanation of the old tool-tip: the damage modifiers of rubies (and `+X min` or `+X max`) on a weapon are calculated before other damage modifiers (like elemental damage for example). Within this, the `+X min` get applied first, taking our example weapon from above to `12 - 15 damage` after this, the `+X max` gets added, resulting in said `12 - 17 damage`.

If we get another weapon with a very small damage range like `10 - 11 damage` it works the same - but after the `+X min` is applied, we get `12 - 11 damage` which doesn't make sense. As a result, the max-damage is raised to `13` and then the `+X max` gets added, resulting in `12 - 15 damage`. We ended up with `+2 min / +4 max`.

Now, if we take a weapon with `10 - 10 damage` (no range), we theoretically end up with `12 - 15 damage` again, which is `+2 min / +5 max` (or `+2-5 damage`) but this doesn't  happen in game as there's always a damage-range, so this possibility was excluded from display.

Conclusion: the old tool-tip showed the *theoretical* maximum effect a ruby could have, which doesn't really happen in-game. Even my second example only happens rarely (only if you put a high ruby in a low-level weapon) so the new tool-tip is much more exact.

Comment: aha! then I did misunderstand the previous calculation. So then how on earth did the old one explain the number 4?

Comment: please see my edit for clearification. the olt tooltip is teh maximum effect a gem can _theoretically_ have. this is still true but happens rarely (and never with full effect since there are no weapons with zero damage range).

Comment: it's a bit confusing, can you fix it up a bit? thanks

Comment: wow, that's very enlightening! I had no idea that a close range value can benefit such a way. I will mark soon once nobody else dis-confirms your post :)

Comment: `+2 min / +2 max` is not the same as `+2-4 damage`.  It's the same as `+2 damage`.  I'm not sure why they decided against that wording...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft They chose the new wording because the old weird edge case with low-damage range weapons still applies. +Min effects are still applied before +Max effects, with all the attendant wierdnesses.

Comment: thanks for the edit/clarification. can we verify this?

Comment: @ericosg what do you mean by verify? You can easily test this in game yourself.

Comment: i've tried myself so far, once i confirm it ill post a screenshot and mark this :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some screenshots validating the damage increase and how the two different tool-tips can be interpreted.

`Before applying gem:`

[image: before applying gem]

If we applied a ruby on it, which says +8-16 damage, or when applied it says +8 min +8 max, this weapon would scale from 23-34 damage, to 31-42 damage.

But when applying a larger gem, such as a flawless square ruby, which says +14-28 damage, or when applied +14 min, +14 max, it now scales to 37-54 damage.

`Gem:`

[image: gem]

`See after applying gem:`

[image: after applying gem]