# What is the difference between +x-y Damage and +x Minimum Damage + y Maximum Damage?

Tags: diablo-iii

I found some rings that add bonus physical damage. Once has +x-y Damage and the other has +x Minumum Damage +y Maximum Damage.

Here is a picture: [image]

Both are from post 1.0.3 and there is still y +x-y Damage attribute contradicting this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74181/does-minimum-damage-and-maximum-damage-tooltip-make-sense).

So my question is how do they differ and would they have the same effect if the value for x and y were the same for both rings (all other attributes ignored). So if the first had +10-12 Damage and the second had +10 Minimum Damage +12 Maximum Damage would they be equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're pretty similar.

So, the first thing you need to know is that flat +Minimum and +Maximum effects *get applied first*, and they do so in a way [described in this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69265/3129). The short version is that the `+Minimum` gets applied first, then, if this causes your weapons `Maximum` damage to be lower than your `Minimum` damage, your `+Maximum` will be increased to `Minimum+1`, and then finally, the `+Maximum` is applied.

Effects that are described as a range work as expected, adding the first number to your weapons `Minimum Damage`, and the second number to your weapons `Maximum Damage`, *simultaneously*, so there should never be any concern about strange overlaps. Bonus Elemental Damage on a weapon works this way as well, and is also applied after flat +Min/+Max effects.